# ignore fields from target class which isn't in target class. MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a problem with mapping fields from through MapStruct.

I have two classes. 
First domain class "Event" for example with fields

```
1) id
2) lastUpdate
2) type
3) participants
4) description
```

And Second class is "EventForm". EventForm have fields:

```
1) type
2) participants 
3) description
```

And when I want to update an existing event, the following happens: 
1) I get an existing event from database by Id

`Event event = eventService.get(id);`

And event have id = 10000, lastUpdate=11213123123;

2) I am mapping fields from form to a domain class

`event = mapper.eventFormToEvent(eventForm)`

3) After that event has NULL value in id and lastUpdate values.

How ignore all unmapped fields in target class?

I will specify that I need all unmapped fields ignore, not one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [updating bean instances](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances). This is what you will need to use for your use case. It uses the `@MappingTarget` annotation.

Your mapper will look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    void update(@MappingTarget Event event, EventForm eventForm);
}
```

or:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    Event update(@MappingTarget Event event, EventForm eventForm);
}
```

In the second case, MapStruct, just returns the passed `event` back. You will have to keep in mind that the parameter passed for `@MappingTarget` must not be `null`.